# Show that $3^{2^n}-1$ is divisible by $2^{n+2}\,\, \forall n \in \Bbb N$

Tags: real-analysis

I am stuck on the following problem:

> Use the principal of induction to prove 
>   that  $3^{2^n}-1$ is divisible  by $2^{n+2}\,\, \forall n \in \Bbb N$

My Attempt: Let us denote the statement by $ \,P(n) \colon 3^{2^n}-1$ is divisible  by $2^{n+2}\,\, \forall n \in \Bbb N$ which can alternatively written as $$P(n):3^{2^n}-1=l(2^{n+2})$$ for some positive integer $l$. Clearly,$P(1)$ holds good. Now I have to show that $P(n+1)$ is true whenever $P(n)$ is true. We see, $$\begin{align}P(n+1) \\=3^{2^{n+1}}-1 \\=(3^{2^n}-1)(3^{2^n}+1) \\=l(2^{n+2})(3^{2^n}+1) \ldots\end{align}$$ Now, I am stuck. My intention was to come to the result of $\,\,k(2^{n+3})$ for some positive integer $k.$

Can someone help? Thanks and regards to all.

Comment: Can you show that the other term contributes at least one power of 2?

Comment: Not necessary. Can you show that the term is even?

Comment: Parity argument. Odd plus odd is even.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Can you accept my answer so that we can mark this question as done?

Comment: @CalvinLin O sure..Accepted...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint:** show that the other term contributes a power of 2, since it is the sum of 2 odd terms.